# The default value of array is 0 in java, why is it not getting printed in my code? when I am taking size of the array from the user

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have the below code wherein I am taking "n" as the size of the array from the user, for testing purpose, I am only providing few inputs, i.e n-1 inputs to the program. My understanding is that the program should take n values from the user and for the (n-1)th value, it should print zero since I have not provided any value, but it is throwing an error.

I am a complete begineer, hence, any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Code:-

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        
        for( int i=0; i<n;i++){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

```
Input Provided:- 
4
1
4
2

Expected output:
1
4
2
0

Actual Output:-




Output
[NonZeroExitCode] Your code encountered a runtime error
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Comment: `sc.nextInt()` is throwing the exception because you didn't enter the last integer. It's not going to return `0` when it finds nothing to read.

Comment: every input consider as string you need  explicitively convert it to number.

Comment: I suggest you prompt the user. Before ` int n=sc.nextInt();` add a line something like `System.out.println ("How many integers do you wish to enter? ");`.  Before `arr[i]=sc.nextInt();` add a line something like `System.out.println  ("(" + i + ") Enter next integer. ");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanner.nextInt()` will explode if there's no integer ready to read from the console.

To get the behaviour you want, you should check if there's an integer ready to read *before* you attempt read it, and stop reading if there isn't one ready to read.

To do this, replace this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

with

```java
int count = 0;
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    arr[count++] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/FSTmJW) that produces your desired output.